# Expected value from a Poisson distributed array

Tags: python, statistics, poisson

Say I have a numpy array with a shape of `(180, )`, the values in which follow a Poisson distribution. I would like to find the expected value from this. How should I achieve that? Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: `np.mean(arr)`.

Comment: To elaborate on what I wrote, you don't (and can't) find the expected value of the underline distribution, whether it is Poisson or something else. You _estimate_ the expected value with some estimator. As for Poisson distribution, the Maximum Likelihood Estimator (MLE) for the mean (so called lambda parameter of the Poisson) is just the (sample) average of the data, hence `np.mean(arr)`.

Comment: @j1-lee Thank you for your clear explanation. That makes a lot of sense now.